# Changing data-tooltip with AJAX isn't working

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django, materialize

I have a button in my html template:

```
            <a class="tooltipped" id="stash_recipe_tooltip" data-position="bottom" data-delay="50"
               data-tooltip="{{ stash_tooltip }}">
                <div id="stash_recipe_btn" class="detail_footer_btn btn-floating col2 center"> + </div>
            </a>
```

later, in the html file, I have:

```
<script>
function  add_recipe_to_stash() {
  var stash_plus_or_minus = document.getElementById("stash_recipe_btn").innerHTML
  $.ajax({
    url: '/ajax/add_recipe_to_stash/',
    type: 'GET',
    data: {
       # this goes to a django view that, in essence, returns a new 'stash_tooltip' var and 'stash_plus_or_minus' var
      'stash_plus_or_minus': stash_plus_or_minus,
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        document.getElementById("stash_recipe_btn").innerHTML = data.stash_plus_or_minus;
        $("#stash_recipe_tooltip").attr('data-tooltip', data.stash_tooltip);  
    }
  });
}
function addClickHandlers() {
  $("#stash_recipe_btn").click( add_recipe_to_stash );
}
</script>
```

It seems like

```
$("#stash_recipe_tooltip").attr('data-tooltip', data.stash_tooltip);
```

should be changing my tooltip, but nothing happens. Any idea how to successfully update the data-tooltip without refreshing the page? I've tried different variations of the above line but I can't get it to update.

Comment: Use the `data()` function instead: `$("#stash_recipe_tooltip").data('tooltip', data.stash_tooltip)`

Comment: Hm, seems to have no effect. :/

Comment: which tooltip library you use?

Comment: can you provide a working example?

Comment: materialize - http://materializecss.com/dialogs.html

Comment: the documentation suggests that `$("#stash_recipe_tooltip").tooltip('NEW TOOLTIP');` might work, but again, it has no effect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `tooltip` function for that:

```
success: function (data) {
    document.getElementById("stash_recipe_btn").innerHTML = data.stash_plus_or_minus;
    $("#stash_recipe_tooltip").tooltip('tooltip', data.stash_tooltip);  
}
```

Comment: Upvoting because this is what the documentation suggests. Doesn't currently work in my code, but maybe there's another issue. Thanks.

Comment: This is **not** what you have in the comment on the question... note the difference...

Comment: `.tooltip('NEW TOOLTIP')` **vs** `.tooltip('tooltip', 'NEW TOOLTIP');`

Comment: Did you try `.tooltip('tooltip', data.stash_tooltip)`? Still doesn't work?

Comment: What do you have in `data.stash_tooltip`? I just tried this code inside the `materialize` website and it works perfect.

Comment: The phrase is dependent upon `stash_plus_or_minus`, but just a str. Functionality is the same when I just use a hardcoded string. 

I'm wondering if the existing tooltip is what's causing it. Like, it won't over-write an existing tooltip.

e.g.
`$("#stash_recipe_tooltip").tooltip({'tooltip': data.stash_tooltip});` works if there's no pre-existing tooltip, but fails to disappear once the mouse moves away.

I think perhaps I also have to remove them:
```
$('#stash_recipe_tooltip').tooltip('remove');
$("#stash_recipe_tooltip").tooltip({'tooltip': data.stash_tooltip});
```
Works!

Comment: In my test I only used `$(el).tooltip('tooltip', 'some new text');` on some element that already have a tooltip and it worked just fine.

Comment: Hm. Has no effect in my code. It might be e.g. some conflict with a materialize-django helper library meant to fix other issues. Anyways, because your answer should work for most people, I'll go ahead and accept it. Thanks for the help. :)

Comment: If you want to show me a more specific example I'll try to help.

Comment: It's cool - I got it to mostly work with the code in my comment above:

`$('#stash_recipe_tooltip').tooltip('remove');`

`$("#stash_recipe_tooltip").tooltip({'tooltip': data.stash_tooltip});`

This doesn't overwrite existing tooltips from the HTML, but I think that should be easy to get around. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: For curiosity, working now :D 


ex: http://www.recipestasher.com/recipes/detail/baked-honey-mustard-chicken,101/

https://github.com/hillarysanders/recipereader/blob/master/home/views.py

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#someElement').prop('tooltipText', 'new title');
```